# How to loop through files in a folder pass a value and insert text into a file

Tags: powershell

Hello I have this code I've been working on to loop through a folder add file name to command line parameter of an executeable then output the results to a text file..
The code works for one interation but does not seem to loop through all the files and append to the text file.
Can you take a look at my structure and see why it is not looping through all the files and appending.
Regards.

```
$Path = "C:\rawfiles"
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\rawfiles\*.001
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    c:\outputfiles\ldump.exe $file.fullName > c:\outputfiles\test9.txt -Append
    "=======End of Batch========" | Out-File c:\outputfiles\test9.txt -Append
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't mix `>` with `-Append`.  Try this instead:

```
$Path = "C:\rawfiles"
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\rawfiles\*.001
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    c:\outputfiles\ldump.exe $file.fullName | Out-File c:\outputfiles\test9.txt -Append
    "=======End of Batch========" | Out-File c:\outputfiles\test9.txt -Append
}
```

Or:

```
$Path = "C:\rawfiles"
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\rawfiles\*.001
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
    c:\outputfiles\ldump.exe $file.fullName >> c:\outputfiles\test9.txt
    "=======End of Batch========" >> c:\outputfiles\test9.txt
}
```

You may want to add a line at the very beginning to delete or empty test9.txt.